# Debezium read from the specified the bin log position

Tags: debezium

Need the debezium to read from a specific position in the bin log. Is it possible? If yes, how can it be specified?

Debezium snapshot modes are:  initial, when_needed, never.
We want to keep the snapshot mode to never and start reading from the specified bin log position.

Answer (score 1):

you can hack it witha source offset manipulation, see https://debezium.io/documentation/faq/#how_to_change_the_offsets_of_the_source_database

Comment: Thank you. I would try this.